# how to check the correct login credentials using a script in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to automation testing and I would like to know how to write a scripts to check whether I have entered a correct login details and if not correct I need to print a message.

```
public class NewTestOssLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:/automation/geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String url = "////test/url////";
        driver.get(url);

        System.out.println("page loaded successfully");

        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("test_vizua1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("sanduni_123");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Login']")).click();

    }
}
```

Here I wrote the script without conditions. I want to know how to write this script with if else conditions.

I'll be thankful if anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

There can be different ways to do this

1. After login your URL redirect to another page then you can use following way-

   ```
   String newUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();

   if(newUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("expected_URL")){
       System.out.println("Login Success");
   }
   else {
       // your further action 
   }
   ```
2. Another way can be, you can locate an element which comes after successful login 
   e.g you can find username of logged in user

   ```
   String usename = driver.findElement(By.yourLocater).getText();
       try {
        if(usename.equalsIgnoreCase("expected username")) {
             // success message
         }
        else {
           // your further actions
        }
      }
       catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
   ```
3. You can use `assert` of `TestNG` framework as well

   ```
   assertEquals(newUrl, driver.getCurrentUrl());
   ```